# Why can't I move after getting out of the Cryo-Chamber?

Tags: fallout-4

In Fallout 4, in the beginning of the game when you get out of Vault 111's Cryo-Pod, I can't move. This is out of the cutscene.

- I am playing on a brand new Xbox One.
- I can open up the Xbox home page and the in-game menu, but I can't move, rotate, crouch or anything else.
- I am using Joystick Controls.
- I can't even move the camera or anything.
- I am updated to the latest patch
- It worked fine for one save file, but not for this current one.

How do I fix this?

Comment: @Sheogorath - is your controller responding at all? Can you access the Xbox menus etc using it?

Comment: We can open up the start menu and in-game menu.

Comment: Push **all** the buttons.  Seriously though, have you tried crouching?  Can you move your camera at all?  Can you go into 3rd person and see if there is anything weird blocking your?  Are you updated to the latest patch?

Comment: I can pause, but not rotate or crouch

Comment: Maybe you're stuck in a conversation or even the screen pan that leads to a conversation.  Pretty sure all of your controls get locked whenever you're in a conversation.

Comment: @SheogorathGaming, based on your edit, does this same contoller work in other first person type games? Sounds like a joystick issue... If it is the game, maybe reinstall fresh offline and see if that help (as a starting point)

Comment: It's brand new. Fallout 4 is the first game I have played on it, and as of now the only game.

Comment: @zero298, not true. You can freely walk out of any conversation in FO4. (Or at least most, to my knowledge anyway). They demoed that at E3.

Comment: @SheogorathGaming, since it's new, see if you're able to get the controller to work on another xbox. If you can't get it to work or don't have one to test it on, it might be worth looking at returning. Can you navigate the menus using the joystick? Or just with the D-Pad?

Comment: @SheogorathGaming, if the xbox is new, you should have a 14 day trial for xbox gold included. After activating xbox gold, you will have access to the "games for gold" title. Knight Squad is one of the current titles, is very small in size, and will tell us if this problem is localised to Fallout 4.

Comment: I don't have another Xbox One, and no one I know has another. It is fine on my other save files. I let my friend make their own profile to play Fallout 4 but it isn't working for hers. It is fine for mine, though.

Comment: So you have other saves with this copy of F4 on this XBox One?  Does this issue keep happening whenever you start new F4 games?

Comment: @zero298 We just got out of the Cryo-Chamber. We can't have a conversation at the point we are. It was working fine up until we left the pod

Comment: @zero298 I just have my save and my friends save

Comment: Try starting a new Fallout 4 game.

Comment: The point of prematurely closing, @Robotnik, is that it prevents users "jumping the gun" and answering with answers that do not apply to OPs problem. Note that it says "too many **possible** answers", not too many *correct* answers. If the question lacks detail, such as this one, users have a lot more **possible** answers. They may not be **correct** answers, which is why we should be narrowing it down **before we let people post answers**. If you think the question is so salvageable, you should not have to worry about reopening it.

Comment: @Timelord64 - No no no, getting multiple answers has **never** been bad! Even if they don't fix the OPs problem, they may fix someone else's problem - the entire point of the SE network is for questions and answers to be useful for more than one person. Closing is for questions that **don't have answers**, or have answers which *don't work well in the Q&A format*. Getting 5-6 different solutions to the problem is how the voting mechanism is *supposed* to work - the better solutions rise to the top.

Comment: That's why we allow editing of your own *and* other's posts, that's why OPs with <50 rep can comment on their own question and answers to that question for clarification - we strive for an answers-first environment and closing to 'prevent early answers' is going against the entire paradigm that SE is built upon.

Comment: Even when you have answers that contradict the question, because you have added in information that the original answerer had no idea about?

Comment: @Timelord64 Yup, especially in that case. The answerer can update it, leave it, or delete it. If it's updated, great! Everyone's happy. If they leave it, then it hangs about at the bottom of the voting order getting a few + or - votes but not going anywhere and is still there for people who stumble across the question later - just in case it turns out to be their solution. And if it's deleted, then the only people that see it are those with >10k rep anyway.

Comment: @SheogorathGaming, when you say this problem only happens on your friends save, is it a separate save file on the same profile, or did you create a separate profile?

Comment: Xbox controllers can get super confused in terms of which account they are suppose to be representing. I have had certain controller functionalities disable, because it understood I was the only account signed in, and it was the only controller, **but I had not specifically said "this is the controller i intend to use**. This sounds like a stupid feature, and its through dumb luck that I get to said interface, but if you have two accounts its a possibility, especially if this only happens on the new account.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common bug. Try restarting the console and see if that helps.

https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3s8lmf/cant_move_after_cryogenic_pod_opens/